# Open local html file in current window with Javascript Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, browser, bookmarklet

I'm trying to build a sample bookmarklet to grab current webpage source code and pass it to a validator. Validator is not a an online website, but a folder with bunch of javascript and html files. I'm trying to open file:///C:/Users/Electrifyings/Desktop/Validator/Main.html file with the help of javascript bookmarklet code and put the source code in the textarea in the newly opened window, but it is not working for some reasons that I'm not aware of.

Here is the sample code with algorithm:

```
javascript:(function(){var t = document.body.innerHTML;window.open('file:///C:/Users/RandomHero/Desktop/test.html',_self);document.getElementById("validator_textarea")=t;})()
```

Here are the steps:

1. Grab current web page source code in a variable.
2. Open locally stored HTML web page in current or new window or new tab (either way is fine with me, but no luck)
3. Put the source code from the variable into the validator textarea of the newly opened HTML file.

I have tried above code with a lot of variations, but got stuck on the part where it opens the new window. Either it's not opening the new window at all or it is opening blank window without loading the file.

Would love to get some help with this issue, thanks a lot.

Oh and btw,

Windows 7 x64, Tried IE, Firefox and Chrome. All latest and stable builds. I guess it's not a browser side issues, but something related to javascript code not opening the URI with file:/// protocol. Let me know if any more details are needed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't want a webpage you visit to be able to open up `file://c:/Program Files/Quicken/YourSensitiveTaxInfo` right?  Because then if you make a mistake and go to a "bad" website (either a sleazy one or a good one that's been compromised by hackers), evil people on the intarweb would suddenly have access to your private info.  That would suck.

Browser makers know this, and for that reason they put VERY strict limits to prevent Javascript code from accessing files on a user's local computer.  This is what is getting in the way of your plan.

Solutions?

- build the whole validator in to the bookmarklet (not likely to work unless it's really small)
- put your validator code up on the web somewhere
- write a plug-in (because the user has to choose to install a plug-in, they get much more freedom than webpages ... even though for Firefox, Chrome, etc. plug-ins are basically just Javascript)

*** * Edit * ***

- Extra bonus solution, if you don't limit yourself to a purely-client-side implementation:

  1. Have your bookmarklet add a normal (HTML) form to the page.
  2. Also add an iframe to the page (it's ok if you hide it with CSS styling)
  3. Set the form's target attribute to point to the iframe.  This will make it so that, when the user submits the form and the server replies back to that submission, the server's reply will go to the (hidden) iframe, instead of replacing the page as it normally would.
  4. Add a file input to your form - you won't be able to access the file within that input using Javascript, but that's ok because your server will be doing the accessing, not your bookmarklet.
  5. Write a server-side script which takes the form submissions, reads the file that came with it, and then parrots that file back as the response.  In other words, you'll have a URL that you can POST to, and when it sees a file in the POST's contents, it will respond back with the contents of that file.
  6. Now that you've got all that the user can pick their validator file using the file input, upload it to your server, your server will respond back with the file it just got, and that file will appear as the contents of the iframe.
  7. And now that you finally have the file that you worked so hard to get (inside your iframe) you can do `$('#thatIframe').html()` and viola, you have access to your file.  You can save the current page's source and then replace the whole page with that uploaded file (and then pass the saved page source back to the new validator page), or you can do whatever else you want with the contents of the uploaded validator file.

Of course, if the file doesn't vary from computer to computer, you can make all of that *much* simpler by just having a server that sends the validator file back; this could be a pure Apache server with no logic whatsoever, as all it would have to do is serve a static file.

Either way though, if you go with this approach and your new file upload script is *not* on the same server as your starting webpage, you will have a new security problem: cross-domain script limitations.  However, these limitations are much less strict than local file access ones, so there are ways to work around them (JSONP, cross-site policy files, etc.).  There are already tons of great Stack Overflow posts explaining these techniques, so I won't bother repeating them here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda knew that browser won't allow me to go to file:/// page from http:// page due to security reasons. So I'm thinking of adding small HTML overlay window to current web page from JavaScript code in bookmarklet. That small HTML overlay will allow ask user if he wants to validate the file and I suppose browser would have no problem redirecting to a local file after getting user initiated action input such as on click. Is this possible or a correct solution?

Comment: If yes, can you give me a sample code to do it, all of the sample codes on Internet are using CSS so no idea how should I add to current opened web page and achieve HTML overlay. Hope you're getting what I'm saying. :-)

Comment: I don't believe that that will work.  Just to clarify, the limitation is this: the browser will NEVER let Javascript code (unless it's inside a plug-in) initiate local files access.  What it will allow however is purely user-initiated file access.  In practice, this kills your idea because, while the click event itself is a user-initiated action, it's handler is just Javascript code; you can't do anything with that handler that you couldn't do in non-handler JS.

Comment: Where does this leave you?  With my previous suggestions ;-)  But, if you really want to keep your current approach, you have no choice: you have to involve the server.  Have you ever noticed sites that let you upload a file, and then immediately after the upload they display a thumbnail preview of it?  I think Facebook/Google+ do it, but I haven't uploaded an image to them recently, so I forget.  Anyhow, the way those sites are able to do that is essentially as follows ... actually, on second thought, this will be hard to explain in a comment; please see the (newly-edited) answer above.